# geth ignoring --ipcpath in Linux with attach and datadir

Tags: go-ethereum, testnets, ipc, datadir

I am trying to create a test network and have been able to start a network (I think).

`geth --datadir ./eth-data --ipcpath geth.ipc attach`

I get

`Fatal: Unable to attach to geth: dial unix /home/victory/.ethereum/geth.ipc: connect: no such file or directory`.

I have also tried with the full path but it always looks in the `~/.ethereum` directory.

According to the help doc I am running `1.4.5-stable`

I would like to know how I can attach to my testnet so I can start mining and testing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this format: `geth --datadir /tmp/geth attach ipc:/tmp/geth/geth.ipc`

(`ipc:` after `attach`)

Source: https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/2634

Answer (score 4):

Have you started a geth node on the same machine before attaching? `datadir`, `ipcpath` and `networkId` are parameters to start a node. While `datadir` parameter change the default data folder position (default ~/.ethereum), `ipcpath` change the default IPC file position (default ~/.ethereum/geth.ipc)

To start a test network use something like:

```
geth --networkid 1234 --datadir /home/victory/.ethereum1234
```

Don't forget networkId parameter and choose your preferred number as identification (avoid well know id like 0=Olympic, 1=Frontier, 2=Morden).

Then you can attach to the node with

```
geth attach ipc:/home/victory/.ethereum1234/geth.ipc
```